# Prove that there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ that is bounded above, where $(x_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers that does not diverge to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-writing

Suppose that $(x_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers that does not diverge to infinity. Prove that there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ that is bounded above. I did a proof but that proof showed that $(x_n)$ is bounded above, which is not necessarily true, so something was wrong with that proof.

Comment: What does it mean, precisely, for $(x_n)$ to diverge to infinity? Then take the negation of this statement -- what does it mean for $(x_n)$ to *not* diverge to infinity? Writing this out carefully should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $x_{n} \not\to \infty$, then  $\exists M>0$ such that for all $N>0$ there exists some $n>N$ such that $x_{n} \leq M$

So if we first take $N = 1$ we have that there exist some $n_{1}>1$ such that $x_{n_{1}} \leq M$

Then we take $N = n_{1}$, so there exist some $n_{2} > n_{1}$ such that $x_{n_{2}}\leq M$

Thus we can construct a subsequence $\{ x_{n_{k}} \}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_{n_{k}} \leq M$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: This is what I did at first but the negation is not true because it implies $(x_n)$ is bounded above when it is not. My professor gave an example of this: $x_n=\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{1}{k}$. Then the sequence does not diverge to infinity but also does not have an upper bound

Comment: $x_{n} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$ is a diverge sequence.

In my proof $(x_{n})$ is not a bounded sequence necessarily. Take the sequence $(x_{n})$ such that $x_{2k} = -1$ and $x_{k} = k$

Then $(x_{n})$ does not diverge to infinity, is not bounded, and $(x_{n_{k}}) = (x_{2k})$ is a bounded subsequence

Comment: Well according to my professor, a sequence that does not diverge to infinity need not be bounded above. Do you know an alternative proof that does not imply $x_n$ is bounded above?

Comment: I agree with this.. read my comment, I edit it.

Comment: But in the proof you wrote that $x_n \le M$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Is that not the definition of M being an upper bound?

Comment: I'm not. I said that for each $N>0$ there exists some $n>N$ sucht that $x_{n}\leq M$



In the example $x_{2k} = -1$, $x_{k} = k$. We have that for $M = 1$, for each $N>0$ we can take the next closest even number $n = 2k$ and then $-1 = x_{2k} = x_{n} \leq M = 1$ 

That does not mean that $x_{n}\leq M $ for all $n$